# Add html tag after second word

Tags: php, addition

I have a variable that contains 4 words.
ex.:

```
$a="asd,dss,asc,dsa"
```

and I want to add a `<br>` tag after second word('dss').How can I do this ?

After adding :

```
$a="asd,dss<br>,asc,dsa";
```

PS. `$a` is not an array.

Comment: what you mean by $a contain 4 words?

Comment: When I select from database $row['locations']="as,as,cd,cs"

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Looks like a ugly workaround for some styling issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$a="asd,dss,asc,dsa";
$arr = explode(",", $a);
$arr[1] = $arr[1]."<br>";
$a = implode(",", $arr);
```

You can make a function to do this task with different parameters (like de "," as separator or the position of the word.

```
function add_br($str, $sep, $pos) {
    $arr = explode($sep, $str);
    $arr[$pos] = $arr[$pos]."<br>";
    return implode(",", $arr);
}


echo add_br("asd,dss,asc,dsa", ",", 1); // output: "asd,dss<br>,asc,dsa"
echo add_br("asd|dss|asc|dsa", "|", 1); // output: "asd|dss<br>|asc|dsa"
```

Comment: Thanks ,This will have this effects : $a="dada,dad<br>,da,ds".How can I remove the ',' after <br>

Comment: @MaximAlexandru that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you are asking but this may helps you

```
echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace('dss','dss<br>',"asd,dss,asc,dsa"));
```

output

```
asd,dss<br>,asc,dsa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a="asd,dss,asc,dsa";
$str = preg_replace('/,/', '<br>,', $a, 2);//will replace 2nd occurence of ',' with '<br>,'
echo $str;
```